# Binding to a Collection of the ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1

I have a problem with the binding in my Windows Phone 8.1 Project, not silverlight.
I got a simple ViewModel containing a `ObservableCollection` and an `int`.

If I use the designer to create a binding, I only can see the `int` Property.

I am trying to bind to the `ItemsSource` Property of the `ItemsControl`
So it should, as far as I understand except a `Collection or List` for binding.

But I only see this:

[image: Screenshot of my binding]

Am I missing something here?

This should be possible.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Nice_Dice"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:uc="using:Nice_Dice"
xmlns:vm="using:Nice_Dice.ViewModel"
x:Class="Nice_Dice.MainPage"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:Dices/>
</Page.DataContext>

<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="Test" ItemsSource="HERE IS WHERE I TRY TO BIND">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
</Page>
```

**Dices.cs (ViewModel)**

```
public class Dices
{
    public ObservableCollection<Outcome> Outcomes = new ObservableCollection<Outcome>();
    public IList<string> Test;
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    public Dices()
    {
        MakeTestData();
    }        
    public void MakeTestData()
    {
        Dice a = new Dice
        {
            Name = "D6",
            States = new ObservableCollection<State>
            {
                new State 
                {
                    Value = "1"
                },
                new State
                {
                    Value = "2"
                },
                new State
                {
                    Value = "3"
                }, 
                new State
                {
                    Value = "4"
                }, 
                new State
                {
                    Value = "5"
                }, 
                new State
                {
                    Value = "6"
                }
            }
        };
        a.States[5].Dice = a;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++)
            Outcomes.Add(a.GetOutcome());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your collection a property instead of a field.  The data binding designer will only show you properties.

Comment: Yes of course... I knew it was something simple ty :D

Comment: Not just the data binding designer, but data binding in general does not work on fields; only properties.